# Do my code may casuse memory leak or too many udp link?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I want to use snmp method to query some data by mutithread in sometime,if over time,then the task will be cancel,I write the code like this, if there is something wrong with my code(It means that the thread may only do step 1and step 2,but do not do the step 4:close snmp connetction),how to fix ?Can I have the method that is the task is cancel,I can still close the snmp clent at step 4?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            100, 100, 0L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100)); 
        System.out.println("Executing first batch of tasks...");
        submitTasks(pool);
        System.out.println("Finish first  batch of tasks..."); 
        //call submitTasks(pool) many times
        ...
     }
  private static void submitTasks(ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException {
    var tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        tasks.add(() -> {
            try {
                //1.create snmp client
                 //2.query data with udp link
                 //3.return result 
                     return result;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                log.error(String.valueOf(ex));
            }  
        } finally {
         //4.close snmp
        if (snmp != null) { 
          snmp.close(); 
        }
        }
            
        });
    }
    List<Future<String>> futureList=executor.invokeAll(tasks,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
        Future<String> future = futureList.get(i);
        try {
            list.add(future.get());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            log.info("timeOut Task：{}", i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    } 
}
```

I have change the code from Alexander Pavlov's example,it seems that if the task is cancel,the finally code will never run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            3, 3, 0L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1));
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing first batch of tasks...");
        submitTasks(pool);
        System.out.println("Executing second batch of tasks...");
    } finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}

private static void submitTasks(ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException {
    var tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>(3);
    final var latch = new CountDownLatch(3);
    log.info(String.valueOf(latch.getCount()));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        tasks.add(() -> {
            try {
                String s="1";
                log.info("this.name:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for(int a=0;a<1000000L;a++) {
                   s=a+"";
                }
                    return s;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                log.error(String.valueOf(ex));
            }finally {
                latch.countDown();
            }
            return  null;
        });
    }
    List<Future<String>> futureList=executor.invokeAll(tasks,1,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
       List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    //latch.await();//
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
        Future<String> future = futureList.get(i);
        try {
            list.add(future.get());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            log.info("timeOut Task：{}", i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    log.info(String.valueOf(latch.getCount()));
    log.info("start to await:");
    try {
        latch.await(); // WAIT UNTIL ALL TASKS ARE REALLY DONE
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        log.error(String.valueOf(ex));
    }
    //never log end to await
    log.info("end to await:");
    log.info(String.valueOf(latch.getCount()));
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error you see?

Comment: Also keep in mind, `invokeAll` with timeout just calls `Thread.interrupt()` for running tasks. It does not wait until task stops. Moreover, some tasks may ignore interruption and continue working. So when you are returning from `submitTasks` then it does not mean all underlying tasks are really stopped.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov,do you mean that if a thread is interrupted,then the finally code will still run?My worry is that the thread is stopped, but the resources are not recycled, such as the connection is not closed（like step 4 in the example）.

Comment: `finally` code will be executed when code within `try` is completed. `Thread.interrupt()` does not stop task. It **notifies** task that interruption is requested. It is up to running code to take notification into account or to ignore it. If you want to be 100% sure that all tasks are stopped when you exit from `submitTasks` then use `CountDownLatch`  to control how many tasks have been really finished and exit when running tasks count is zero.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov,·finally code will be executed when code within try is completed.·I am worried that if the code in try is not executed completely when it is interrupted, will it continue to execute and then execute the code in finally  part? Or is it possible that the thread exits directly before the code in try finally  executing？

Comment: @ user3022220 Interruption is just advice to worker thread. It is up to code to take it into account or to ignore. Interruption cannot prevent execution of `finally`. However, it also cannot guarantee when `finally` will be executed. In other words, in your current code, when `invokeAll` is completed, it does not mean that all or some or any tasks are completed. When `invokeAll` is completed it means each task is either completed or notified that it needs to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invokeAll` with timeout just calls `Thread.interrupt()` for running tasks. It does not wait until task stops, it **notifies** task that interruption is requested. Moreover, some tasks may ignore interruption and continue working. So when you are returning from `submitTasks` then it does not mean all underlying tasks are really stopped.

If you want to be 100% sure that all tasks are stopped when you exit from `submitTasks` then use `CountDownLatch` to control how many tasks have been really finished and exit when running tasks count is zero.

```
private static void submitTasks(ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException {
    var c = 100;
    final var latch = new CountDownLatch(c); // EXPECT 100 TASKS TO BE COMPLETED
    var tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        tasks.add(() -> {
            try {
                //1.create snmp client
                //2.query data with udp link
                //3.return result
                return result;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error(String.valueOf(ex));
            } finally {
                //4.close snmp
                if (snmp != null) {
                    snmp.close();
                }
                latch.countDown(); // 1 MORE TASK IS COMPLETED
            }
        });
    }
    List<Future<String>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(tasks, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < futureList.size(); i++) {
        Future<String> future = futureList.get(i);
        try {
            list.add(future.get());
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            log.info("timeOut Task：{}", i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    try {
        latch.await(); // WAIT UNTIL ALL TASKS ARE REALLY DONE
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be  after 100 tasks is completed because of timeout,I should check which task have close snmp and which do not close  snmp client. I need additional actions to close these snmp clients that are not closed in the task.It that right?

Comment: code above uses `CountDownLatch` to ensure that you do not exit from `submitTasks` until all snmp clients are closed, so I do not think you need additional action to check tasks.

Comment: No,the result i run is that is task is cancel,the finally code will never run.You can see my code example in the question from your code.

Comment: Finally,I find that  List<Future<String>> futureList=executor.invokeAll(tasks,1,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); will runs the result as you say, If I change TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS to TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS,the finally code will never run.

Comment: If you set it to 1 nanosecond then probably task is cancelled even before it is started